# Generating dynamic jasper report from tabledatamodel

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

I am trying to generate a jasper report using a tabledatamodel, as

```
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(model);
JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), dataSource);


        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
```

when I run this code I get following error, if anyone can help me to come-up with this problem.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ar.com.fdvs.dj.domain.DynamicJasperDesign.setPrintOrder(B)V
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DJJRDesignHelper.getNewDesign(DJJRDesignHelper.java:69)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperDesign(DynamicJasperHelper.java:207)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:535)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:518)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:283)
        at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:236)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has something to do with the jasper reports version you are using, try downgrading. The issue was reported [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3394896&group_id=188060&atid=923805)

Comment: could you please tell me the the suitable versions of jasper report and dynamic jasper to generate a dynamic jasper report.

Comment: Dynamicjasper 3.1.9 was released on 23 of June, 2011, so I guess it should work with Jasprereports 4.0 or if not, then with 3.7 version

Comment: I can confirm that version 4.0.0 works with DynamicJasper 3.2.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mainly because of jar file mismatches. It depends on which Jasper version you are using with DynamicJasper. On DynamicJasper's [download page](http://dynamicjasper.com/download/) you will find information about compatibility versions here is summary:

- DJ 5.x works with JasperReposrts 4.6.+
- 5.x and 6.0.x. (JDK 1.6 needed)
- DJ 4.x workrs with JasperReports 4.1 to 4.5.x
- DJ 3.0.5 works with JR 3.5 up to 4.0

For future updates refer http://dynamicjasper.com/download/ for version compatibility.